# Why did the Roma continue to come to Paris in spite of Frollo's persecution of their people?

Tags: the-hunchback-of-notre-dame

Specifically in reference to the 1996 Walt Disney animated feature *The Hunchback of Notre Dame* (which made several key changes to the story as contained in the original literary source) — why did the Roma continue to come to Paris despite knowing of Frollo's hatred for them, and his eventual intent to wipe them out?

Esmeralda's troupe were in the city for the Festival of Fools, but Quasimodo's parents came from outside of Paris, appeared to have a life independent of the city, and were not traveling there for the Festival.

Other Roma also continued to travel to the city after the festival was over.

Was this ever addressed in the animated feature or any external material?

Comment: You could ask the same thing of many immigrants in the present day.

Comment: Please stay on topic.

Comment: @AaarghZombies - It seems pretty on-topic to me. Why do people travel from X to Y if some people are mean to them when they get to Y? Because their lives are pretty shitty in X already, and might be less shitty in Y.

Comment: In addition to that, in some countries, you have, every year, communities moving to or through the country for like a pilgrimage or a fest or whatever the name is. Some are very welcome because they being a lot of business, but some aren't *that* welcome.

Comment: @Valorum, it's off topic because it's related to the 1996 Disney movie. Could all comments\answers please directly frame things in the context of the movie.

Comment: @OldPadawan, are you able to relate that to anything in\out of universe with the Disney movie?

Comment: @AaarghZombies: not at all :)